# How to fix bug after install module on Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I have a following problem  after installing module ["M2E Pro Amazon & eBay Integration"](https://github.com/m2epro/magento2-extension)

```
composer require m2epro/magento2-extension:dev-master
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Exception:

```
[zzbusyco@nwpro5 public_html]S php bin/magento setup:upgrade Cache cleared successfully File system cleanup: /home/zzbusyco/public_html/generated/code/Amazon /home/zzbusyco/public_html/generated/code/Composer /home/zzbusyco/public_html/generated/code/Dotdigitalgroup /home/zzbusyco/public_html/generated/code/MSP /home/zzbusyco/public_html/generated/code/Magento /home/zzbusyco/public_html/generated/code/Symfony /home/zzbusyco/public_html/generated/code/Temando /home/zzbusyco/public_html/generated/code/Yotpo The directory '/home/zzbusyco/public_html/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup /home/zzbusyco/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml /home/zzbusyco/public_html/pub/static/deployed_version.txt /home/zzbusyco/public_html/pub/static/frontend Updating modules: Schema creation/updates: SQLSTATE[42502]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'zzbusyco magen17.mgjj_catalog_category_flat_store_1' doesn't exist, query was: SHOW CREATE TABLE mgjj_catalog_category_flat_store_l
```

The error page shown by Magento 2.3.3 when loading the home page:

```
There has been an error processing your request 
Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. The following modules are outdated: Ess_M2ePro schema: current version - none, required version - 1.4.3 Ess_M2ePro data: current version - none, required version - 1.4.3 
Error log record number: 841519020354
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Instead of providing links to images, please paste and format your error into the question.

Answer (score 0):

"M2E Pro Amazon & eBay Integration" is a Magento 2 extension that allows you to integrate your Magento 2 store with Amazon and eBay, so that you can list and sell your products on these platforms directly from your Magento store.

To install the "M2E Pro Amazon & eBay Integration" module on your Magento 2 store, you will need to follow these steps:

Purchase the extension from the official website or a Magento Marketplace.

Login to the backend of your Magento 2 store as an admin user.

Go to the System menu, and then select the Web Setup Wizard.

Click the "Component Manager" link to start the component manager.

In the component manager, select the "M2E Pro Amazon & eBay Integration" component and then click the "Install" button.

The extension will be installed and you should see a success message.

Clear the cache and log out of the backend, then log in again.

Go to the Stores > Configuration > M2E Pro > General and enter the License Key from M2E Pro account.

After the setup is completed, you can find the new M2E Pro menu in the top of the admin sidebar, and you can start configuring the integration with Amazon and eBay.

It's worth noting that this is a rough instruction and your specific installation process could vary depending on your platform and hosting environment.
It is also recommended to take a backup of your website before making any major changes.
It is also a good idea to consult the extension documentation or contact the developer for further assistance on the installation and setup of the module.